# Return Column Names when True in R

Tags: r

I am using R for a project and I have a data frame in in the following format:

```
  A B C 
1 1 0 0 
2 0 1 1
```

I want to return a data frame that gives the Column Name when the value is 1.

i.e.

```
  Impair1 Impair2
1    A       NA
2    B       C
```

Is there a way to do this for thousands of records? The max impairment number is 4.

Note: There are more than 3 columns. Only 3 were listed to make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through the rows of your data, returning the column names where the data is set with an appropriate number of `NA` values padded at the end:

```
`colnames<-`(t(apply(dat == 1, 1, function(x) c(colnames(dat)[x], rep(NA, 4-sum(x))))),
             paste("Impair", 1:4))
#   Impair1 Impair2 Impair3 Impair4
# 1 "A"     NA      NA      NA     
# 2 "B"     "C"     NA      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the apply family of functions, here is a general solution that should work for your larger dataset:

```
res <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  out <- character(4) # create a 4-length vector of NAs
  tmp <- colnames(df)[which(x==1)] # store the column names in a tmp field
  out[1:length(tmp)] <- tmp # overwrite the relevant positions
  out
})

# transpose and turn it into a data.frame
> data.frame(t(res))
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  A         
2  B  C
```